# Using RxJava how can I execute asynchronous tasks with multiple dependencies

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm learning rxjava and converting some of my codebase to see how it works. Currently I am trying to wrap my head around using Observables or Completables to accomplish executing tasks (task execution has no relevant return value) with dependencies such as:

**Execution**

Tasks: A, B, C, D, E

- B depends on A
- C depends on B, D
- E depends on D

So the task execution could look like:

```
execute A, D  
D completes -> execute E  
A completes -> execute B  
B completes -> execute C (B, D both completed)
```

**Questions**

- Taking in an arbitrary dependency graph is something like this a good use case for rxjava?
- Is this even a use case for observables/completables?
- If so: what is a technique for implementing such behavior?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [concat()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) and [merge()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)  operators to achieve this.

Here is how it can be done :

```
package rxtest;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;


public class RxJavaDagTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RxJavaDagTest.class);
    private static Executor customExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    @Test
    public void stackOverflowTest() {
        Observable<Character> a = createObservable('A', 100);
        Observable<Character> b = createObservable('B', 200);
        Observable<Character> c = createObservable('C', 500);
        Observable<Character> d = createObservable('D', 150);
        Observable<Character> e = createObservable('E', 200);

        logger.info("BEGIN");

        // As Observable for D is referred at two places in the graph, it needs to be cached to not to execute twice
        Observable<Character> dCached = d.cache();

        Observable.merge(
                Observable.concat(
                        Observable.merge(
                                Observable.concat(a, b),
                                dCached),
                        c),
                Observable.concat(dCached, e))
                .toBlocking()
                .subscribe(i -> logger.info("Executed : " + i));

        logger.info("END");
    }

    private Observable<Character> createObservable(char c, int sleepMs) {
        Observable<Character> single = Observable.just(c)
                .flatMap(i -> Observable.<Character> create(s -> {
                    logger.info("onSubscribe Start Executing : {}", i);
                    sleep(sleepMs);
                    s.onNext(Character.valueOf(i));
                    s.onCompleted();
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(customExecutor)));
        return single;
    }

    private void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be :

```
20:47:05.633 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest BEGIN
20:47:05.745 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : A
20:47:05.748 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : D
20:47:05.849 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : A
20:47:05.850 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : B
20:47:05.899 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : D
20:47:05.899 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : D
20:47:05.899 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : E
20:47:06.051 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : B
20:47:06.051 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest onSubscribe Start Executing : C
20:47:06.100 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : E
20:47:06.552 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest Executed : C
20:47:06.552 [main] INFO rxtest.RxJavaDagTest END
```

Comment: This example executes in proper order, then hangs. I think something needs to be added to terminate the executor threads, like ExecutorService.shutdown() maybe, but I'm not sure where it should be added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of a general purpose tool to create and run a DAG using RxJava. I don't claim to be an expert in Reactive theory or RxJava specifically, and acknowledge I might not be doing things at all optimally. This code uses Lombok and JOOL to eliminate boilerplate; if there's interest I can supply a version in plain old Java.

```
package reactivedag;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.val;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

import static io.reactivex.Observable.*;
import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool;
import static org.jooq.lambda.Seq.seq;

public class ReactiveDag {

    public static <T> Observable<T> runAsReactiveDag(
            List<T> ts,
            Function<T, List<T>> tPredsFn,
            Function<T, List<T>> tSuccsFn,
            Consumer<T> jobLogic) {
        val ctx = new Context<T>(newFixedThreadPool(ts.size()), tPredsFn, tSuccsFn, jobLogic, new HashMap<>());

        val dag = seq(ts)
                .map(t -> {
                    Observable<T> pred = createObservable(t, ctx);
                    List<T> succTs = ctx.tSuccsFn.apply(t);
                    return createAndMergeDag(succTs, pred, ctx);
                })
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .findSingle()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No DAG was created"));
        dag.subscribe(x -> {}, x -> {}, () -> {
            ctx.executor.shutdown();
        });
        return dag;
    }

    private static class Context<T> {
        @NonNull final ExecutorService executor;
        @NonNull final Function<T,List<T>> tPredsFn;
        @NonNull final Function<T, List<T>> tSuccsFn;
        @NonNull final Consumer<T> jobLogic;
        @NonNull final Map<T, List<Observable<T>>> deferredMerges;

        Context(ExecutorService executor, Function<T, List<T>> tPredsFn, Function<T, List<T>> tSuccsFn, Consumer<T> jobLogic, Map<T, List<Observable<T>>> deferredMerges) {
            this.executor = executor;
            this.tPredsFn = tPredsFn;
            this.tSuccsFn = tSuccsFn;
            this.jobLogic = jobLogic;
            this.deferredMerges = deferredMerges;
        }
    }

    private static <T> Observable<T> createObservable(T t, Context<T> ctx) {
        return just(t)
                .flatMap(tee -> Observable.<T> create(emitter -> {
                    ctx.jobLogic.accept(t);
                    emitter.onNext(t);
                    emitter.onComplete();

                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(ctx.executor)));
    }

    private static <T> Optional<Observable<T>> handleSuccessor(
        Observable<T> upstreamDag,
        T succT,
        int numUpstreamNodes,
        Context<T> ctx) {

        if (numUpstreamNodes == 1) {
            val newUpstreamDag = concat(upstreamDag, createObservable(succT, ctx));
            val newSuccTs = ctx.tSuccsFn.apply(succT);
            return createAndMergeDag(newSuccTs, newUpstreamDag, ctx);

        } else if (numUpstreamNodes > 1) {
            //this successor will have to be merged: either add to deferrals or merge now...
            List<Observable<T>> deferred = ctx.deferredMerges.getOrDefault(succT, new ArrayList<>());
            if (deferred.size() < numUpstreamNodes - 1) {
                //not all merge partners are constructed yet: add to deferrals
                deferred.add(upstreamDag);
                ctx.deferredMerges.put(succT, deferred); //often redundant, benignly
                return Optional.empty();
            } else {
                //ready to merge: merge the current and all deferred upstreams, remove the deferral entry, and
                //continue building the downstream recursively
                deferred.add(upstreamDag);
                val mergedUpstream = merge(deferred);
                ctx.deferredMerges.remove(succT);
                return handleSuccessor(mergedUpstream, succT, 1, ctx);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("successor " + succT + " is not expected to have zero predecessors");
        }

    }

    private static <T> Optional<Observable<T>> createAndMergeDag(
            List<T> ts,
            Observable<T> upstreamDag,
            Context<T> ctx) {

            if (ts.isEmpty())
                return Optional.of(upstreamDag);

            val maybeWrappedUpstreamDag = ts.size() > 1
                    ? upstreamDag.cache()
                    : upstreamDag;

            val observables = seq(ts)
                .map(succT ->
                    handleSuccessor(maybeWrappedUpstreamDag, succT, ctx.tPredsFn.apply(succT).size(), ctx))
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .toList();

            return observables
                .isEmpty()
                    ? Optional.empty()
                    : Optional.of(observables.size() > 1
                    ? merge(observables)
                    : observables.get(0));
    }
}
```

I'm using this tool to process all the objects in a somewhat elaborate model, and it simplifies the task substantially. It's overkill for the OP's problem, but for illustration, here's a solution based on the above ReactiveDag class:

```
package reactivedag;

import lombok.val;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import static reactivedag.ReactiveDag.runAsReactiveDag;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger;

public class Sample {
    private static final Logger log = getLogger();

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        val dag = runAsReactiveDag(asList('A', 'D'),
            c -> {
                //predecessor getter function
                switch (c) {
                    case 'B': return asList('A');
                    case 'C': return asList('B', 'D');
                    case 'E': return asList('D');
                    default: return emptyList();
                }
            }, c -> {
                //successor getter function
                switch (c) {
                    case 'A': return asList('B');
                    case 'B': return asList('C');
                    case 'D': return asList('C', 'E');
                    default: return emptyList();
                }
            }, c -> {
                //job logic
                log.info("Starting " + c);
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                log.info("Ending " + c);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > Taking in an arbitrary dependency graph is something like this a good
   >   use case for rxjava?

Well, based on the RxJava documentation, it seems definitely a use case for RxJava

> RxJava is a Java VM implementation of Reactive Extensions: a library
>   for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using
>   observable sequences.
>
> It extends the observer pattern to support sequences of data/events
>   and adds operators that allow you to compose sequences together
>   declaratively while abstracting away concerns about things like
>   low-level threading, synchronization, thread-safety and concurrent
>   data structures.

2. > Is this even a use case for observables/completables?

If you don't need the result of the operation, but you just need to know if it completes, then `Completable` is good.

3. > If so: what is a technique for implementing such behavior?

I don't know if there is a specific technique that can help transforming your problem in RxJava code.

I would do something like this:

```
Single.zip(
            executeA()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .andThen(executeB())
                    .toSingleDefault(""),
            executeD()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .andThen(new CompletableSource() {
                        @Override
                        public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableObserver cs) {
                            executeE().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                    .subscribe(() -> Log.d("test", "complete E"));
                            cs.onComplete();
                        }
                    })
                    .toSingleDefault(""),
            (BiFunction<String, String, Object>) (s, s2) -> s)
            .flatMapCompletable(o -> CompletableObserver::onComplete)
            .andThen(executeC())
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> Log.d("test", "start"))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> Log.d("test", "complete C"));
```

where the tasks are defined as `Completable` in the following way:

```
private Completable executeA() {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        Log.d("test", "completing A");
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

private Completable executeB() {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        Thread.sleep(12000);
        Log.d("test", "completing B");
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

private Completable executeC() {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Log.d("test", "completing C");
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

private Completable executeD() {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Log.d("test", "completing D");
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

private Completable executeE() {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Log.d("test", "completing E");
        e.onComplete();
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm not sure about the approach that I used to solve the problem of `andThen` part attached to `executeD()`. We cannot just concatenate D and E in this way :

```
executeD().andThen(executeE())
```

because otherwise the task C will start after E, but we want it to start after D. This is way I created the CompletableSource that execute the task C and at the same time allow the continuation of the execution calling `onComplete()`.

Note also that in this implementation I have two subscriptions: one for each end of path (end of C and end of E).